# htaccess - rewrite & redirect without a causing a loop

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

**Old site:**

www.example.com (default)

**New site:**

example.com (default)

and for a new language..

es.example.com

**Currently on the old site:**

www.example.com/this-page.php

**Wanted on the new site (clean urls):**

example.com/this-page

es.example.com/esta-pagina


**So far I have this:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^this-page/?$ this-page\.php?lang=$1
RewriteRule ^esta-pagina/?$ this-page\.php?lang=$1
```

** The $_GET['lang'] is generated internally depending on whether example.com or es.example.com is hit.

**The Question:**


How can I also add a redirect similar to this:

Redirect 301 /this-page.php http://example.com/this-page

...that doesn't cause a infinite loop?

Comment: Why can't you use an additional RewriteCond for the rule that evaulates the HTTP_HOST?

Comment: @arkascha I'm a rewrite dummy - can you give me a clue on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I also add a redirect similar to this:
>   Redirect 301 /this-page.php http://example.com/this-page
>   ...that doesn't cause a infinite loop?

You need to match against the actual request and not the URI. The URI will change as the rewrite engine loops through the rules.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD|POST)\ /this-page\.php(\?|\ )
RewriteRule ^ /this-page [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Also worth noting that the %{HTTPS} check will give you the infinite loop error if you're using a CDN like CloudFlare. If you're a CloudFlare user you'll need to replace RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on with this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
```